# Plotting a stacked column containing a categorical list using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a Pandas dataframe with categorical data stored in a list. I would like to plot a stacked bar plot with col3 on the x-axis and col1 and col2 stacked on top of each other for the y-axis.

Reproducible dataframe structure:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    d = {'col1': [1, 17, 40], 
         'col2': [10, 70, 2], 
         'col3': [['yellow', 'green', 'blue'], 
                  ['yellow', 'orange', 'blue'], 
                  ['blue', 'green', 'pink']]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df.explode('col3').set_index('col3').plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

Or:

```
df1 = (df.explode('col3')
        .melt('col3')
        .pivot_table(index='col3', columns='variable', values='value', aggfunc='sum'))

df1.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```